# Are all retracts with the same homotopy type as the bigger set, deformation retracts?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the book of james r munkres about topology and noted that if A is a deformation retract of X, A and X need to have the same fundamental group. But is a retract that has the same fundamental group as the bigger set automatically a deformation retract.

Like is $[0,1]$ a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}$. and how does one construct a continous map like in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract.

Kees

Comment: To your second question: Consider $F(x,t)=\begin{cases}
   \text{sgn} x \tan \frac{\pi t}{2} & \text{if } |x| > \tan \frac{\pi t}{2} \\
   x       & \text{if } |x| \leq \tan \frac{\pi t}{2}
  \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Let the smaller set be a point; as mentioned in Jesus RS's answer, there is always a retract onto any point in a space. (The constant map!) Instead of just assuming that your larger space has the same fundamental group as the point, even if you assume that they're homotopy equivalent (i.e., the larger space is contractible), that's not sufficient to say that your space deformation retracts onto the point.

A space that doesn't deformation retract onto *any* point is given in exercise 0.7(b) of Hatcher's algebraic topology book.

Comment: Just as a complement one can say that in the end homotopy type is not that far from deformation retracts: any equivalence of homotopy can be decomposed into  sequence of deformation retracts (up and down, so to say).

Answer (score 0):

A point is a retract of any space, hence a point of the sphere is a retract of the sphere. The point and the sphere have both trivial fundamental group, but the point is not a deformation retract of the sphere (for instance, the second homotopy group of the sphere is $\mathbb Z$, not trivial).